# How to redeploy java web app cargo

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-cargo

Dear friends I'm running my java web-app with cargo-maven2-plugin. When I run

> mvn cargo:run

everything works well, but i modify my sources and run

> mvn cargo:redeploy

i get the following error:

```
        [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 18:17:04,411 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext (ApplicationContext.java:675) - Servlet InitServlet threw unload() exception
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.destroy() for servlet InitServlet threw exception
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.unload(StandardWrapper.java:1339)
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.stop(StandardWrapper.java:1654)
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4345)
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:892)
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:979)
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1187)
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:292)
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1305)
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1569)
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1578)
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1558)
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 27-feb-2014 18.17.11 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
    [INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFO: Deploying web application archive myApp.war
```

and it remain in this manner. 
How can I solve this trouble?